# Remove whole word only with Java

Tags: java, regex

How can I remove the **whole word** `on` (**not the substring** `on` in the `Confirmed`) from the following string?

```
X-JP409 Confirmed on 13/2/12
```

Comment: If it's always going to be that format, just replaces `" on "` with `" "`?

Answer (score 10):

There is special marker of word in regex: `\b`. So the better way is `myString.replaceAll("\\bon\\b", "");`

This works when word 'on' is in the beginning, end and in the middle of the text but only if it is a separate word. For example it will not remove "on" from word "one".

Comment: +1 for the using the correct assertion for this task, I will leave superfluous whitespace in the string, but to handle this correctly some cases would be needed.

Comment: @101010 [String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: @stema will `replace()` take a regex?

Comment: @stema : will you please look on this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char, char))?  Be polite!

Comment: @101010, OK, No, replace is not accepting a Regex, only a char. But replaceAll is accepting as first argument a String that is a regex.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to replace all "on" which are not in a word, you can try to match the **word boundary \b** as well.  Hope it helps.

```
    String abc = "on X-JP409 Confirmed on 13/2/12 on";
    abc = abc.replaceAll("\\bon\\b", "");
    System.out.println(abc);
```

or

```
    String abc = "on X-JP409 Confirmed on 13/2/12 on";
    abc = Pattern.compile("\\bon\\b").matcher(abc).replaceAll("");
```

`replaceAll` is actually invoking the `Pattern` api.

Answer (score 3):

```
"X-JP409 Confirmed on 13/2/12".replace(" on ", " ");
```

[String replace documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace)

Comment: The second argument of replace() should be " ", not just "", because it will make the two word "Confirmed" and "13/2/12" to one word.

Comment: This answer technically answers the question but only works when the target word is in the middle of the sentence. The answers below (using replaceAll with RegEx) are better as they both answer the question and in a manner that is more universal / educational as to how to generally solve word replacement challenges.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
String str = "X-JP409 Confirmed on 13/2/12";
str.replaceAll(" on ", " ");
```

The output is what you are looking for:

```
X-JP409 Confirmed 13/2/12
```